# Size of the conjugacy class of the element σ = (1, 2, 3)(4, 5) in the group Sym5 . Order of the centraliser CSym5 (σ)

Tags: group-theory, permutation-cycles

I am a little confused with this question. Am i right in looking for all the elements in Sym5, that are conjugate to $\sigma$ , in other words $a = b\sigma b^{-1}$ for $a,b \in $ S5

ther will be 5 single cycles correct? I am not sure what else
EDIT: Do I have to work out EVERY single permutation.. from
(1) ,(12) ,(12)(34) ,(12)(34), (123) , (1234), (12345)
and multiply a cycle above by $ \sigma $ and its inverse??

Also, the definition of a centraliser is that of a subset of a group, so is the second part saying $\sigma$ is a subset?

Comment: You are correct that your looking for all $a$ for which there exists $b\in S_5$ with $b\sigma b^{-1}$; in other words, the cardinality of the set $\{b\sigma b^{-1}\mid b\in S_5\}$. But I think there are a lot more than $5$ single cycles. The centralizer of a single element is the centralizer of $\{\sigma\}$, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Conjugate permutations have the same cycle type.  And permutations with the same cycle type are conjugate.  Thus you want to count the number of $3$-cycles.  There are $20$, I believe.

Next you can use the orbit-stabilizer theorem.  Consider the conjugation action.  We get that the stabilizer, which is the centralizer, has order the index of the order of the orbit.  So $5!/20=6$.